# Why are MacOS Automator variables marked differently?

Tags: macos, automator

Some variables in Automator have a letter "V" and some a gear, as shown below.   What is the significance of these icons, e.g., are their corresponding variables different in some way, such as what one can do with the variable?

The Automator User Guide doesn't appear to say anything about it.

[image: pic].

Comment: Each library item has a description if the view is enabled (button in lower left toolbar), but the gear icons represent a constant value such as a path, while the V icons are variables that you can also name and specify a value (text, script, etc) or format (date, time, etc).

Comment: Thanks @red_menace, makes sense (I added an answer quoting your comment).  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As *red_menace* pointed out in the comments,

> "Each library item has a description if the view is enabled (button in
> lower left toolbar), but the gear icons represent a constant value
> such as a path, while the V icons are variables that you can also name
> and specify a value (text, script, etc) or format (date, time, etc)."

Still haven't been able to find a documentation reference to this information.